# Instantiate typed IEnumerable of compile-known type by reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Using only .net 3.5 i have sample class:

```
public class Table1
{
   public IEnumerable<Table2> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Its a kind of ORM and i need materialize collection by a lazy computed type

I trying find way to assign instance to property  **Items**, 
 for example by `List<Table2>`

When i create instance by Activator, it returns object, which i cant cast to needed type

```
var t = typeof(List<>);
var gt = t.MakeGenericType(typeof(Table2));
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(gt);

var table1 = new Table1();
table1.Items = instance; //canot use cast here
```

And is problem to assign 'object' variable to typed IEnumerable

How it works in most OR-mapers?

Can i use Reflection.Emit to generate concrete type?
Can i use Castle/Linfu?

EDIT:

I canot use any direct cast, because it requires reference **Table2** which is i cannot harcode

SOLUTION:

After some time i found solution by myself. It need to use reflection for set instance:

```
var table1 = new Table1();
var table1Type = typeof(Table1);
var prop = table1Type.GetProperty("Items");
prop.SetValue(table1, instance, null);
```

Comment: "which i cant cast to needed type" - why not?

Comment: Austin Salonen, see edit

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a simple cast:

instead of:

```
table1.Items = instance;
```

make it:

```
table1.Items = instance as IEnumerable<Table2>;
```

Comment: I canot use any direct cast, because it requires reference Table2 which is i cannot harcode

Comment: Well can you change the declaration of the `Items` property in `Table1` to an `object` then?

Answer (score 0):

If you know you want a List why can't you just use `new List<Table2>()`? Generally you only use `Activator.CreateInstance` when the type isn't known until runtime, often using a string-based configuration value.

All you need to do, though, is explicitly cast `instance` to either `IEnumerable<Table2>` or `List<Table2>`, either one should work:

```
table1.Items = (IEnumerable<Table2>) instance;
```

Comment: I canot use any direct cast, because it requires reference Table2 which is i cannot harcode

Comment: @devi You have a reference to Table2 in your code: `var gt = t.MakeGenericType(typeof(Table2));`

Comment: its just sample, in my code i use GetType() instead of typeof() and types not referenced